# iOS 13 UIWindowScene how to lock orientation?

Tags: ios, screen-orientation, ios13, uiscene

I want to use SceneDelegate, UIWindowScene, UIWindowSceneDelegate and other UIScene related things.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    window = UIWindow.init(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene

    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "FCBottomTabBar", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()!
    window?.rootViewController = vc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

How can i dynamically lock the orientation for this window? For example for `portrait` only? Dynamically means that in runtime when user interacts with something the orientation locks back to all.

For example for screen A i need to lock to only portrait orientation. For screen B to only landscape.

Comment: I want to know too.

Answer (score 0):

From 'Device orientation' initially make it portrait.

In AppDelegate make a variable 'orientation' and set its value to UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    ...
    var orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return orientation
    }
}
```

Now in your desired ViewController write this to change orientation

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).orientation = .landscapeLeft
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626510/10871073) seems overly complex and uses a private API. In a view controller, to set the supported orientations, simply override `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

For example, to lock it to Portrait orientation:

```swift
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    .portrait
}
```